# How can I read and write on the same file without opening / closing it

Tags: python-3.x, file

I would like to know if it is possible to read and right in a file without having to open and close it ?

This is what I would like to do :

```
file = open("a_file.txt", "w+")
file.write("some text")
print(file.read())
```

This does not work as it yields an empty string rather than the `"some text"` I whish to obtain.

Most of the answers I found recommend to close the file first and then open it again such as this :

```
file = open("a_file.txt", "w+")
file.write("some text")
file.close()
file = open("a_file.txt", "r")
print(file.read())
file.close()
file = open("a_file.txt", "w+") # open it again as I will write more into it later
```

or will recommend something like this where I only open it when needed :

```
with open('a_file.txt','w+') as f:
    f.write("some text")
with open('a_file.txt','r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Neither of those seem very efficient and as I need to read and write in those files a lot I am looking for an efficient way.
I could store the content of the file in a separate variable but it just beats most of the purpose of having a file in the first place.

Is there an efficient way to do what I require or am I stuck with lots and lots of open / close ?

Comment: The open and close methods you've show are actually pretty efficient. You can open the file in a read+writable mode. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Open file in `r+` mode.

Comment: why would you need that ever? you can always read initial contents, update, write - no need to re-read as current file contents in your data variable you used for writting also to avoid bugs prefer using with statement to manipulate files.

Comment: very efficient may turn into a not that efficient if called a few thousand times a loop. what I am wondering is if it's the best I will get or if there is more efficient ?

Comment: most efficient will be in memory operations with variable and write back to file only once - when done; instead of re-reading your own updates

Comment: @Drako I agree with you, I need to do this to test a log system to make sure it functions correctly and this implies to stress test it. It - thank goodness - does not work this way in usual circumstances

Comment: Reading and writing advances the current position in the file. You have to ``file.seek`` back to the beginning if you want to read/write from an earlier point.

Comment: it more looks like HW test not software test for me at the moment; but agree with @MisterMiyagi on seeking back to start if you really want to do this

Comment: I now think that I need to re-think my approach to this problem as I am just going to end up with more issues than solutions

Comment: "I could store the content of the file in a separate variable but it just beats most of the purpose of having a file in the first place." What *is* the purpose of having a file in the first place?

Comment: long term storage but this is for runtime tests so no long term here. Should have been a little more precise there